# Is it ok to call someone a jackass for their comment

Tags: discussion

I would normally answer this as no but there are situations that arise that might require the use of socially accepted language above PG-13. So is it considered bad taste to call out someone who is a jackass in their comments? I would figure appropriate labeling would be held above the use of language here? Am I correct?

Since we really like examples this comment on a recently answered question of mine brings the point to a head. I posted a bounty saying I wanted an authoritative source. When pressuring the answerer I receive the linked response. 
[Variables in Rails Routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431150/variables-in-rails-routing/27508206?noredirect=1#comment43456726_27508206)

Can I call him what I would term to be an appropriate label?

Comment: Nope, not even if it's me.  If it's severe enough, flag for moderator attention and move on.  The last thing you want to do is provoke anything.  In fact, if you *were* to call him that, odds are *your* comment would get flagged instead.  Mission Not Accomplished.

Comment: If you asked for an authoritative source and got a smart aleck response, ignore, flag unconstructive if it's serious enough, continue. Don't you dare press that `Add Comment` button.

Comment: Attack the message (politely and via moderation flag if severe) but not the messenger.

Comment: Good answers I hope that flagging an individual comment would not detract from the answer itself correct?

Comment: @davidbates If I provided you a good answer and then called you a vegetable in a comment, that doesn't change the answer's quality, but the comment is unnecessary. If it's in the answer, it may be rolled back to before the snarkiness.

Comment: It won't detract from the answer, but really, the comments seem so tame, I'm having a hard time understanding why you'd want to call him names.  And I love calling people names.

Comment: Amen, to @LittleBobbyTables comment. He's not really being a jack*** in his comment as it's not all that bad; he's just not being helpful either. Move on.

Comment: It was the bold statement of "Consider me the source. I'll "allow" you to use Ruby code in a Ruby file" after I pressed for an authoritative source. Maybe just inflated ego. But it made the question come to mind. btw I love LittleBobbyTables!

Comment: `"Maybe just inflated ego"` -- you may be reading more into it than the rest of us see. I see it as he's saying that he doesn't have the reference that you're requesting but that he's familiar enough with the library to know for a strong fact that his answer is correct. This may not be ego but fact.

Comment: Could be, the fact he put a smiley face at the end of it should make it ok... right?

Comment: I can see where you're coming from, but if there's no source, there's no source, and now he's the source. Sometimes a person has to take the first step and document it.

Comment: I should say that I had already given him the bounty before this comment relevant to Compass comment that he may be the source since I have yet to find documentation of anyone else doing this. But I did feel perturbed by it... enough so that I wanted to call him out, but I see the err of my ways.

Comment: So many negatives for a question that spurred a great set of responses on how to handle situations where language might get involved?

Comment: Don't misunderstand meta voting either. Negative on meta means that we don't agree with the question's premise and has nothing to do with the question's merit. I voted -1 for instance because I don't think that you should call him a JA.

Comment: Ahh consider me schooled

Comment: out of curiosity, was it in a quote from Stack Exchange blog? ["You, sir, are a jackass..."](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/ "Stack Exchange is not a forum: the role of “niceness” on a Q&A site")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** [Be nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

> Focus on the post, not the person. That includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to posts (like "lazy", "ignorant", or "whiny").

Comment: Very nice, I hadn't read that page. Now that I have I can clearly see that it is against the SO model to name call. Good reference